# Всплывающие подсказки

Tags: jquery, css3, html, javascript, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне реализовать всплывающие подсказки (ошибки) в правом верхнем углу экрана, похожие на те, которые реализованы на этом сервисе.

Например: Похожие на те, которые отображаются на Хэшкоде когда кто-то отвечает на Ваш вопрос.

Так же интересно узнать Ваше мнение - как лучше реализовать такие всплывающие подсказки с помощью jQuery или HTML + CSS?

Помогите, направьте в правильное русло. Буду очень благодарен любой помощи. Возможно кто-то предложит решение основанное на HTML + CSS3.

Comment: есть хорошие плагины для этого, [jGrowl](http://chernev.ru/jgrowl-vsplyvayushhie-bloki.html) например, их огромное кол-во на любой вкус, погуглите в этом направлении

Comment: Спасибо, обязательно гляну, но сначала попробую сам реализовать, без плагинов. HTML и CSS я уже сделал, осталось только разобраться с jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно на нативе написать "самоделку". Это легко, надо создать `<div>` с `id` потом у него изменять свойство `display` или `visible` стиля например так:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="charset" content="utf-8">
<title>Моё уведомление</title>
<style>
#notice{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 50%;
    width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #897fff;
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
}
</style>
<script>
    var timeout;
    function hideNotice(){
        var notice = document.getElementById("notice");
        notice.style.visibility = "hidden"; // просто скрываем
        // (не влияет на расположение других элементов)
        //notice.display = "block"; //а так вообще убираем из разметки
        timeout = clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
    function notify(text){
        var notice = document.getElementById("notice");
        notice.style.visibility = "visible";
        notice.innerHTML = text;
        timeout = setTimeout("hideNotice()",2000);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="notice"></div>
<input type="button" value="Предупредить" onclick="notify('Уведомление...')">
</body>
</html>
```

Но лучше использовать "фабричные" библиотеки а не "изобретать велосипед" IMHO

Comment: `setTimeout("hideNotice()",2000);` facepalm

`setTimeout(hideNotice,2000);`